# Determine Disk Geometry on Windows using JNA

Tags: java, jna

Could someone please advise on how to get Disk_Geometry in JNA.
I know this is straight forward in C++ by creating a handle for a disk using CreateFile(), using Deviceiocontrol to query it and using DISK_GEOMETRY to get different disk attributes. I would like to be able to do the same thing in Java using JNA, but DISK_GEOMETRY type is missing in the Kernel32.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extend the interface definitions provided with JNA to add anything that's "missing".  You can add any function, structure or constant definitions that suit your purpose.

```
public interface MyKernel32 extends Kernel32 {
    public class DISK_GEOMETRY extends Structure {
        // Fill in specifics of the structure here, following the type mapping rules
        // in the JNA documentation, or use [JNAerator][1] to auto-generate the mapping.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks guys for your help. I am considering both options and will update soon.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to do this with JNA but would like to suggest you to use WMI instead. The WMI class `[Win32_DiskDrive][1]` seems to be a good candidate for you. It contains what you need and probably even more. Now the question is "how to call WMI from java?" There are number of ways. The simplest one is to write script using JScript or VBS and call it from java using `ProcessBuilder`. This way is simple and does not require dealing with native code and external libraries but could be a little bit slow because process-to-process communication is used.

Other way is to use one of available java-to-com packages. For example JaWin, JInterop, JIntegra.